# Is it possible to implement a Swift SequenceType that contains nil elements?

Tags: swift

I want to implement a custom iterable class that can contain nil elements, similar to `[Any?]`. Conforming to SequenceType mostly works except the contract of `GeneratorType.next()` says it should return nil when all elements have been exhausted. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Related: [How do Generators whose Element is Optional know when they've reached the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36253481/2792531)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a (quite silly) example:

```
struct OddSequence : SequenceType {

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int?> {
        var current = 0
        return GeneratorOf<Int?>() {
            if current >= 6 {
                return nil
            }
            current++
            if current % 2 == 0 {
                return current
            } else {
                return Optional(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}


for x in OddSequence() {
    println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
nil
Optional(2)
nil
Optional(4)
nil
Optional(6)
```

The generator returns an optional (which can be `Optional(nil)`) for each element,
and `nil` if the sequence is exhausted.

See also ["Optionals Case Study: valuesForKeys"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12) in the Swift blog about the difference between `nil` and
`Optional(nil)` and its applications.

---

**Update for Swift 2:**

```
struct OddSequence : SequenceType {

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Int?> {
        var current = 0
        return anyGenerator {
            if current >= 6 {
                return nil
            }
            current++
            if current % 2 == 0 {
                return current
            } else {
                return Optional(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

for x in OddSequence() {
    print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create `SequenceType` protocol conforming objects that return `Optional`s. However, because it can be easy to make mistakes, you have to be really cautious when implementing your [`next()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_GeneratorType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/GeneratorType/s:FPSs13GeneratorType4nextuRq_S__FRq_FT_GSqqq_S_7Element_) method (using a custom `GeneratorType` protocol conforming object) or when implementing your [`anyGenerator(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs12anyGeneratorurFFT_GSqq__GCSs12AnyGeneratorq__) closure parameter (using `AnyGenerator`).

As a rule of thumb, you should always follow this pattern:

> If you use a custom `GeneratorType` protocol conforming object and want it to return `Int?`, you will have to set the return type of your `next()` method to `Int??`.
>
> In the same way, if you use an `AnyGenerator` instance and want it to return `Int?` (`AnyGenerator<Int?>`), you will have to pass a closure of type `() -> Int??` to your `anyGenerator` method.

---

#### Using a custom generator

The following Playground code, inspired by @Martin R's answer, shows how to implement a `SequenceType` protocol conforming `Struct` with a custom `GeneratorType` protocol conforming struct that returns `Optional`s:

```
struct OddGenerator: GeneratorType {
    var i = 0
    
    mutating func next() -> Int?? {
        if i >= 4 {
            return Int??.None
            //return Optional.None // also works
            //return nil // also works
        }
        i += 1
        return i % 2 == 0 ? i : Optional<Int>.None
        //return i % 2 == 0 ? Optional.Some(i) : Int?.None // also works
        //return i % 2 == 0 ? .Some(i) : .Some(Optional<Int>.None) // also works
        //return i % 2 == 0 ? Optional(i) : Optional(nil) // also works
    }
}

struct OddSequence: SequenceType {
    func generate() -> OddGenerator {
        return OddGenerator()
    }
}

for x in OddSequence() {
    print(x)
}

/*
prints:
nil
Optional(2)
nil
Optional(4)
*/

let array = Array(OddSequence())
print(array) // prints: [nil, Optional(2), nil, Optional(4)]
```

Note that if you replace `return i % 2 == 0 ? i : Optional<Int>.None` in the previous code with `return i % 2 == 0 ? i : Optional.None`, your for loop will print nothing and your array will be empty.

Also note that if you replace `return Int??.None` in the previous code with `return Int?.None`, you will generate an infinite loop of `nil`.

---

#### Using `AnyGenerator`

The following Playground code shows how to implement in a very cautious way a `SequenceType` protocol conforming `Struct` with an `AnyGenerator` instance that returns `Optional` elements:

```
struct OddSequence: SequenceType {
    
    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Optional<Int>> {
        var i = 0
        let generator: AnyGenerator<Optional<Int>> = anyGenerator {
            () -> Optional<Optional<Int>> in
            
            if i >= 4 { return Optional<Optional<Int>>.None }
            i += 1
            return i % 2 != 0 ?
                Optional<Optional<Int>>.Some(Optional<Int>.None) :
                Optional<Optional<Int>>.Some(Optional<Int>.Some(i))
        }
        
        return generator
    }
    
}

for x in OddSequence() {
    print(x)
}

/*
prints:
nil
Optional(2)
nil
Optional(4)
*/

let array = Array(OddSequence())
print(array) // prints: [nil, Optional(2), nil, Optional(4)]
```

The previous sequence can be rewritten in a much concise but *kind of* less safe style:

```
struct OddSequence: SequenceType {
    
    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Int?> {
        var i = 0
        let generator: AnyGenerator<Int?> = anyGenerator {
            if i >= 4 { return nil }
            i += 1
            return i % 2 != 0 ? Optional(nil) : i
        }
        
        return generator
    }
    
}
```