# How do Generators whose Element is Optional know when they've reached the end?

Tags: swift

The Swift [GeneratorType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_GeneratorType_Protocol/index.html) reference says about the `next` method:

> `next()` Advance to the next element and return it, or nil if no next element exists.

And then in the discussion, it says

> Requires: `next()` has not been applied to a copy of `self` since the copy was made, and no preceding call to `self.next()` has returned `nil`. Specific implementations of this protocol are encouraged to respond to violations of this requirement by calling `preconditionFailure("...")`.

If the Generator is for an Optional type, then it is possible for it to reach a `nil` value before reaching the end of the sequence. How does Swift know that it has not reached the end in this case?

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794849/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-swift-sequencetype-that-contains-nil-elements.

Comment: Related: [Optional binding of nil literal vs. variable that is nil in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26613195/2792531)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to note that whatever type a generator is generating, it wraps that type in an optional.

The `GeneratorType` protocol declares an associated type which it calls `Element` and a method, `next()`, whose return type is of type `Element?`.  Whatever `Element` is, `next()` wraps it in an optional (and remember, optional is just an enum).

So a generator generating optionals wraps those optionals in another optional layer.

Consider the following:

```
let array: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4, nil, nil, 7, 8, nil, nil, 11]
```

This is an array of optional integers.

So if we call `generate()` on this array, it will give us something that returns type `Optional<Optional<Int>>` or `Int??` from the `next()` method.

[image]

The first two calls to `next` will give us values (1, then 2).  The third looks like it returns `nil`:

[image]

But effectively this is just misleading information.  Realistically, the third return is actually this: `Optional.Some(nil)`

We can see that there are more values to generate by looking at this `while` loop, which is terminated by the *real* `nil` that is generated after 11:

[image]

All of the `nil` values we see print are actually `Optional.Some(nil)`, and when the `next()` call finally returns `Optional.None`, the loop terminates.

What we're looking at here is the difference between the following three values possible values:

```
let optionalSomeValue: Int?? = 3
let optionalSomeNil: Int?? = Optional.Some(nil)
let optionalReallyNil: Int?? = nil
```

Note that the second line could also be written as:

```
let optionalSomeNil: Int?? = Optional.Some(Optional.None)
```

At the end of the day, we have to keep in mind that optional is just a generic enum:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}
```

There is no restriction on what `T` can be, which means it can itself be an optional, and it could be an optional with case `None`.

In Swift, the `nil` keyword is just a convenient shortcut for `Optional<T>.None` and the `?` syntax for declaring optionals is likewise a convenient shortcut for `Optional<T>.Some`.  Consider that the following two lines are equivalent in every manner except the variable name:

```
let foo = Optional<Int>.None
let bar: Int? = nil
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've instantly learned tons about Swift and am a little more informed when I put `?` and `!` in my code.

Comment: Please don't put `!` in your code.  You're not a Jedi.